# PHP XSLTProcessor and passing data into PHP functions

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I need to access some XSL data from registered PHP function in XSLTProcessor. I found how to pass current node into the function.

XSL:

```
<xsl:value-of select="php:function('foo', node())" />
```

PHP:

```
function foo($node)
{
    # Here we go, we got DOMNode array and as a consequence - DOMDocument
    var_dump($node);
}
```

OK, this part works fine. Problem is in the second part: I need to pass into PHP function all XSL variables that are visible at the call point. Or, I need to obtain XSL variable value by name from PHP function somehow. And here is the problem - I can't find how to do that. May be some special XPath request? Or some special function? Or some special trick? Or something else?

Comment: You are especially constrained by scope here, so your PHP function can't see "outside." You will need to pass the needed variables as parameters.

Comment: `node()` will pass a set containing the child nodes (elements, text nodes, etc. but not attributes) of the current node, you want `.` for the current node itself.

Comment: Ok, ok, but may be there is some trick to pass all XSL variables as node list (as a result of some tricky XPath request) or something?